# Python statement seems to have no effect

Tags: python, get

I'm attempting to write a function that checks to see if a website is valid by returning "Pass" if the text is greater than 0, but having a hard time doing so. I'm using Pycharm and my line of code **elif str(len(resp.text)) > 0** is giving me trouble. Below is the entire code. I'm currently converting to a string but I've tried it without the string function as well. Thanks in advance.

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def url_check(url, multiplier=1):
    """
    Makes http request. If HTML or XML format is found, will return text, otherwise return none
    """
    time.sleep(2*multiplier)
    try:
        with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
            if is_good_response(resp):
                elif str(len(resp.text)) > 0
                    print('Pass')
                else:
                    print('Fail')
            return None

    except RequestException as e:
        log_error('Error during request to {0} : {1}'.format(url, str(e)))
        return None

def is_good_response(resp):
    """
    Will return True if response is HTML. Will return False if otherwise
    """
    content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
    return(resp.status_code == 200
           and content_type is not None
           and content_type.find('html')> -1)
def get_data(year):
    year = input()
    raw = url_check("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_{}_totals.html".format(year))
    html = soup(raw, 'html.parser')
#Gets headers from table
    soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)
    headers = [th.getText() for th in soup .findAll('tr',limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]
    headers = headers [1:]
    headers

def log_errors(e):
    print(e)
```

Comment: You don't need the `str` - it means your comparing a string with a number (0).

Comment: As an aside, this isn't a "PyCharm statement". It's just Python. PyCharm is an IDE and it shouldn't have any bearing on the behaviour of your code. (Any affect it _does_ have is likely due to virtualenvs or environment variables or Python versions or something else that's not fundamentally part of PyCharm.)

Comment: So if I were to run this in the cmd prompt it could work?

Comment: No, that's the opposite of what I'm saying. Running this code with the same version of Python, libraries, etc. should be the same in PyCharm or the terminal. You still need to fix the Python problem: `str(len(...)) > 0` is a logic bug.

Comment: Got it. I've made the necessary changes and it's running, but its taking a while. I added the elif statement to hopefully cut down on the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `str` to compare 0 which is a number, You should compare the number with a number. Try without `str`.
`len(resp.text)>0`

Also you have syntax errors as well in the if block and function call for `log_error` which should be `log_errors`, fix it like this.

```
with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
     if is_good_response(resp):
         if len(resp.text) > 0:
             print('Pass')
         else: 
             print('Fail')
     return None
```

Modified code is here..

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import time


def url_check(url, multiplier=1):
    """
    Makes http request. If HTML or XML format is found, will return text, otherwise return none
    """
    try:
        with requests.get(url) as fb:
            if is_good_response(fb):
                if len(fb.text) > 0:
                    print('Pass')
                else: 
                    print('Fail')
            return fb.text

    except RequestException as e:
        log_errors('Error during request to {0} : {1}'.format(url, str(e)))
        return None


def is_good_response(resp):
    """
    Will return True if response is HTML. Will return False if otherwise
    """
    content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
    return(resp.status_code == 200
           and content_type is not None
           and content_type.find('html') > -1)


def get_data():
    year = str(input('Enter the year: '))
    raw = url_check(f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_{year}_totals.html")
    html = soup(raw, 'html.parser')
# Gets headers from table
    headers = [th.getText()
               for th in html.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]
    headers = [tag.replace('%', '') for tag in headers[1:]]
    print(headers)


def log_errors(e):
    print(e)

# Invoke the program
get_data()
```

Comment: It seems to be working but it's taking a long time to run. I'd like to avoid the code attempting to return the full text and just tell me if it's greater than 0 to cut down on the runtime. At least that was my thought process. Any suggestions on making it run more efficiently are welcomed.